# What does 'per unit frequency' refer to?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, thermal-radiation, frequency, intensity

We were discussing Kirchoff's theorem on blackbody radiation in class today and the equation was: $$e_{f}= J(f,T)$$

$e_f$ was defined as power per unit area per unit frequency.
What does per unit frequency refer to here? I know what per unit time means but don't understand 'per unit frequency'.

Answer (score 5):

The blackbody radiation is radiation
with not only *one* frequency (e.g. like in a laser beam).
Instead it is a *mixture* of many frequencies
(essentially all frequencies from $0$ to $\infty$).

Therefore it doesn't make much sense to ask for the radiation
power at a single frequency $f$.
But it makes perfect sense to ask for the radiation power
in a frequency *range* (from $f_1$ to $f_2$).

*Power per unit area and per unit frequency* just means
the power emitted from an area of $1$ m$^2$
in a frequency range of $1$ Hz
(for example in the range from $500$ THz to $500.000000000001$ THz).

The spectrum below shows the radiation power per
area (measured in m$^2$) and per *frequency range* (measured in Hz)
as it varies depending on the frequency (here given in THz).

[image]
<sub>image from [Energy eduation | Blackbody radiation](https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Blackbody_radiation)</sub>

Comment: Hi Thomas. 2 questions. 1)so if calculate energy for frequency = 10Hz, it will return the energy radiated in the range of 10-11Hz right ? 2) If we take another equation, which includes wavelength, what would per unit wavelength means ? Lets say I input 3m as a wavelength in the equation, what wavelength range would I get the energy - 3m -> 4m ? But this is a quite bit range no ? Thoughts ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze Spectral density is defined as a *limit for small ranges*. So the spectral density at a frequency $f$ is 
$\lim_{\Delta f\to 0} (\text{energy between }f\text{ and }f+\Delta f)/\Delta f$.
And likewise likewise the spectral density at a wavelength $\lambda$.

Comment: yes, but you mentioned per unit frequency as 1Hz and it is not small range then.  I mean, if you take the wikipedia formula and put wavelength  λ=3, (note that wikipedia formula does not include multiplication by  dλ. What do you get ? Density over what wavelength interval ? I thought in that case we go to SI System and per unit wavelength is 1m. So if I dont multiply the result on   dλ, then it is the density per range of 3–>4m wavelengths. No ?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, power per unit area gives the intensity. So, basically, $e_f$ is denoting the Intensity per unit frequency. It can give an idea about intensity of radiation absorbed by the black body for a range of frequency.