# What is "power per unit frequency" in black body radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, classical-electrodynamics, thermal-radiation

What is the meaning of power radiated by a black body per unit frequency?
If you have a black body with a frequency filter around it set to 530nm and you calculate the energy radiated in 1 second 
you will get a definite (not a differential) value. So where does "per unit frequency" come from? What is its physical meaning?
Edit:
There is a physical anamoly in my argument as, suppose, at 530 nm we get 5 watt energy, so at 530.01 nm the power will approximately be the same 5 watt, and similarly for 530.001nm.
But I still don't get the flaw in my argument (even though I get that the result is wrong). What is it that I am missing?

Comment: See this : https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/495955/234064

Comment: The first answer to the question satisfies your question.

Comment: I don't think it does. The duplicate question's answer doesn't satisfy me too as he doesn't explain why is it reasonable to look at f to f+df rather than just f.

Comment: Read his answer carefully. Looking at f just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why does it not make sense here but does so in a laser ?!

Comment: That is just a special case where all the effect of all the surrounding frequencies is diminished to the maximum possible extent in order to recieve a single, monochromatic and amplified ray of light.

Comment: @Aman, laser light is (ideally) [coherent](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/optmod/qualig.html#c4), monochromatic light, i.e., the power is concentrated in a single frequency. Contrast that with, for example, the light of an incandescent light bulb where the [power is distributed over a *continuum* of frequencies](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/2200K_Spectrum.jpg/1920px-2200K_Spectrum.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is its physical meaning?

It means that, to find the power within a given bandwidth, one *integrates* the power spectral density (PSD) over that bandwidth.

Assuming the PSD is essentially flat over a 1 Hz bandwidth, the power at the output of an ideal bandpass filter, centered at 530 nm and with 1 Hz bandwidth, would be the value of the PSD at 530 nm multiplied by 1 Hz.

If the bandwidth were 1 mHz, the power would be 1000 times less. For an arbitrarily small bandwidth, the power would be arbitrarily small, i.e., the power *at* a specific frequency (wavelength) is infinitesimal.

Keep in mind that no physical bandpass filter has infinitesimal bandwidth.

---

> suppose, at 530 nm we get 5 watt energy

As I wrote above, the power *at* a specific frequency (wavelength) is infinitesimal so you won't find a finite amount of power *at* 530 nm *unless* there is a delta function in the PSD there (for example, due to the output of an ideal 530 nm laser source). But the ideal blackbody spectrum is continuous.

Comment: my filter is hypothetical just like a black body. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: In your hypothetical, how much energy do you get at $t=\frac 1 2$ seconds? You get zero watts, because the time duration is $0$, but there is finite power (energy per time). Likewise, over 1 second, you get zero energy at 565.65THz because the bandwidth is zero, but within a finite bandwidth you get finite energy. I suggest you do not mix frequency and wavelength until you resolve the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Aman, the internet has been down here for awhile.  I've added some to my answer but I'm not quite clear on what you're looking for regarding 'a bit more'.

Comment: @Alfred you hit on my point exactly in the edit. Just tell me why power at a 'specific' frequency is infinitesimal.

Comment: @Aman, I can't quite understand why you think it shouldn't be infinitesimal. Are you asking why is the black body spectrum continuous? Or are you asking why a [continuous spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_spectrum) implies infinitesimal power at a specific frequency?

Comment: Considering black body spectrum to be continuous leads to a physical anomaly as pointed to in my edit. Please help me resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

Planck's distribution function gives the intensity of the emitted radiation (emitted power per unit area) per unit of a physical quantity (frequancy, wavelength, wavenumber) from a Black Body at absolute temperature T.

You can calculate the same for a frequency interval. Let's say you wanted to set the filter from 530nm to an interval of 400nm-530nm.

https://www.spectralcalc.com/blackbody/planck_blackbody.html